# Render google map in Page Block Section

Tags: visualforce, rendered, google-map

My Vf page have 3 steps. And I'm try to show google map in step 3.

```
 <apex:PageBlockSection title="Google Maps" columns="2">
            <body> 
                <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" value="{!Address}" autocomplete="on"/>              
                <div id="map"></div> 
            </body>
 </apex:PageBlockSection>
```

But when I open the 3rd step my map is blank. If I show google map in step 1, on load the map displays correctly.

What I'm missing for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apex:map` to discuss google kind of map in Visualforce.

```
<apex:map width="500px" height="175px" zoomLevel="15" mapType="roadmap" 
            center="{!accountObj.ShippingStreet},{!accountObj.ShippingCity},{!accountObj.ShippingState}">
      <apex:mapMarker title="{!accountObj.Name}" 
        position="{!accountObj.ShippingStreet},{!accountObj.ShippingCity},{!accountObj.ShippingState}"/>
</apex:map>
```

For more information, refer [apex:map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm?search_text=apex:map)